# Select distinct column value when multiple clauses on other columns are satisfied

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select distinct values of a column, with the additional clause that the multiple rows for that value should satisfy all criteria (amongst them).

For example, in the below table I want to say: "Distinct `Name` where `key=1 AND value=2` AND `key=2 AND value=2`".

This should return "valid" only. "invalid1" fails because although it satisfies the first criteria, no other row satisfies the other criteria. "invalid2" fails because it satisfies neither criteria.

```
id         Name      Key       Value
======   =========   ====   ===========
1           valid     1          2
2           valid     2          2
3          invalid1   1          2
4          invalid2   1          3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `group by` with `having`. The conditions in `having` are treated as booleans and return 1 for true and 0 for false.

```
select name
from t
group by name
having sum(key=1 and value=2)=1 and sum(key=2 and value=2)=1
```

Comment: That did it! Is there a way to add an additional optional "where" clause onto that? i.e. it fulfills all those criteria OR "another_column=X"?

Comment: Or am i forced to do that as a separate query?

Comment: better include it in the `having` clause itself.